# Public Web Instances can't update (apt-get) when routing though igw with an ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connectivity, vpc, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC configured with public and private subnets.

My Public Instances seat behind a ELB (internet-facing) and route outbound traffic to the igw.  The SG for the Public instances allows 80+443 traffic inbound and my ELB forwards 80+443 traffic to them.

With this set-up I can access the public web instance via the ELB DNS name but my problem is when I ssh onto the instances I can't update them (apt-get) or access webpages (wget).

I don't have EIPs assigned to the public web instances as I will be setting up Auto-Scaling soon and i don't believe its required.

If I route the public web instances out via the NAT instance apt-get/wget etc will work but my ELB dns name will stop working.

Can someone explain to me what the correct setup should be?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is within your outgoing security rules. I'm not a debian/ubuntu user so I'm not familiar with apt-get, but with yum you can specify what servers you connect to for your updates, find an IP of an update server that is fast for AWS and add it to your outgoing rules for 80/443 and you should be able to update then.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, it's not just updates it's all internet access wget, ping etc.Currently the SG allows alls 80 + 443.  Although the public instances use the igw its not enough to let them direct connection to the internet.
I now understand that the only way I can get my web instances access to the internet is by either giving them an EIP or by placing them in the private subnet and have the NAT do the routing for them.  The first option isn't ideal when your Auto-scaling as it requires you to manually add EIPs but the second option should work fine as long as I have the ELB in the public subnet.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Sorry, I didn't understand your configuration fully. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Although the public instances use the igw its not enough to let them direct connection to the internet. I now understand that the only way I can get my web instances access to the internet is by either giving them an EIP or by placing them in the private subnet and have the NAT do the routing for them. The first option isn't ideal when your Auto-scaling as it requires you to manually add EIPs but the second option should work fine as long as I have the ELB in the public subnet.